# Close Bootstrap Alert based on modal confirm dialog choice

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

The button below that has the data-dismiss="alert" attribute displays a Bootstrap 2 modal dialog so the user can confirm whether or not to close the alert.

Right now **the Bootstrap "alert" (which is a div on the UI, not a popup) closes before the user even selects anything in the modal confirm popup**.

How can I get the Bootstrap "alert" (div)  to close or stay open based on what the user chooses in the modal popup dialog?

```
<div class="span8 see-all-notifications">
    <div id="notification-list" class="module main-slot-c">

            @foreach (var notification in Model.Notifications)
        {
            <div class="noti-alert">
                <div class="alert alert-info">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"
                            data-notificationid="@notification.NotificationId"
                            data-contactpointid="@notification.ContactPointId"
                            data-apiurl="@Url.Content("~/api/account/")">
                        x
                    </button>
                    <h5>
                        <i class="icon-file @notification.EventCategoryIdentifier"></i> @notification.Description <span>Reported at @notification.RaisedDate</span>
                    </h5> 
                    <div class="noti-collapse">
                        <div class="noti-collapse-inner">
                            @notification.Body
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }


    </div>
</div>

<div id="deleteNotificationConfirmModal" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none; ">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
        <h3>Confirm Deletion of Notification</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <h4>Are you sure you want to delete the notification?</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a id="notificationDeleteConfirm" href="#" class="btn btn-success">Delete Notification</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the relevent part of the javascript file

```
// This function wires up the code to "close" the notification (set status to "Read")
$('.noti-alert').each(function(){
    $(this).bind('close', function () {

        var notificationId = $(this).find('button').data('notificationid');
        var contactpointId = $(this).find('button').data('contactpointid');
        var url = $(this).find('button').data('apiurl');

        $("#deleteNotificationConfirmModal").modal('show');

        $('#notificationDeleteConfirm').on('click', function () {


            //"Delete" the notification --> CloseNotification method in api controller
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url, 
                data:{
                    notificationid: notificationId,
                    contactpointid: contactpointId
                },
                success: function (data) { },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert("error" + err.status + " " + err.statusText);

                }

            });

            $('#deleteNotificationConfirmModal').modal('hide');



        });



    });
});
```

});

**EDIT:   Here's the final code I got to work.  I needed to call `e.preventDefault` and then close the "alert" by calling the `thisAlert.remove();` method in the ajax success callback**

```
// This function wires up the code to "close" the notification (set status to "Read")
        $('.noti-alert').each(function(){
            $(this).bind('close.bs.alert', function (e) {

                e.preventDefault();

                var notificationId = $(this).find('button').data('notificationid');
                var contactpointId = $(this).find('button').data('contactpointid');
                var url = $(this).find('button').data('apiurl');

                $("#deleteNotificationConfirmModal").modal('show');

                // set a reference to the notification so we can remove it in the ajax call below
                var thisAlert = $(this);


                $('#notificationDeleteConfirm').on('click', function () {


                    //"Delete" the notification --> CloseNotification method in api controller
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: url, 
                        data:{
                            notificationid: notificationId,
                            contactpointid: contactpointId
                        },
                        success: function (data) {

                            $('#deleteNotificationConfirmModal').modal('hide');
                            thisAlert.remove();
                        },
                        error: function (err) {
                            alert("error" + err.status + " " + err.statusText);
                        }
                    });



                });

                // bind modal's close button click event
                $('.notificationDeleteCancel').on('click', function () {
                    // close modal    
                    //alert('cancel');
                    $("#deleteNotificationConfirmModal").modal('hide');
                });



            });
        });

    });
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle to help with the troubleshooting? http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `$('#deleteNotificationConfirmModal').modal('hide');` on your `success` function of the AJAX call.

This is because you are using an ajax call (which is asynchronous)

For example:

```
 success: function (data) {        
        $('#deleteNotificationConfirmModal').modal('hide');
},
```

**UPDATED code below:** 
**[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R8GgV/2/)**

```
// This function wires up the code to "close" the notification (set status to "Read")
$('.alert-info').each(function () {
    // show confirmation dialog when closing alert message
    $(this).bind('close.bs.alert', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
    });
});

// bind modal's close button click event
$('.notificationDeleteCancel').on('click', function () {
    // close modal    
    alert('cancel');
});

// bind modal's delete notification button click event
$('.notificationDeleteConfirm').on('click', function () {
    // do ajax
    alert('delete');

    //"Delete" the notification --> CloseNotification method in api controller
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/echo/json/",
        data: 'mydata',
        cache: false,
        success: function(json){
            $("#myModal").modal('hide');
            $('.alert-info').alert('close');
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert( 'error');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: ok maybe I should do that, but the problem is getting the alert on the UI to stay open or to close based on the confirm dialog choice that the user selects.

Comment: the "alert" I'm referring to is not a popup but a Bootstrap "alert" which is just a div on the UI.

Comment: Have you tried binding to `close.bs.alert` instead? See docs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts

Comment: Just tried binding to close.bs.alert - it seems to bind the same as close.  What I need is a way to cancel the close on the UI and keep the alert visible if the user selects cancel on the modal popup.  The problem is the alert closes as soon as you click the button, before the modal popup is even displayed.

Comment: updated my code to be more independent of button clicks... looks like to you have to use `preventDefault()` - see updated code above and fiddle as example.  The code may not be 100% perfect but it will get you past your hurdle (I believe)

Comment: Thanks for the help blurfus.  I really appreciate it.